# Data type mismatch in criteria expression From Excel file through OLEDB

Tags: excel, oledb

I am processing an uploaded file through a ASP.NET page. I am using the following connection string:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
     excelFile + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";
```

Here is the SQL statement:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [req_tf_order_no] <> ''";
```

Here is the code that loops through the DataReader

```
   using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
   {
       using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
       {
           command.CommandText = sql;
           connection.Open();
           using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
           {
               if (reader.HasRows)
               {
                   hasMoreData = reader.Read();
                    while(hasMoreData)
                   {
                            ...
                            hasMoreData = reader.Read();
                           if (hasMoreData == false)
                           {
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
```

Here is most of the stack trace:

```
(Error Description: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.)
(Stack Trace: at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader() at ...
```

If I don't include the WHERE clause(`WHERE [req_tf_order_no] <> ''`), I don't get any error. The only reason for the WHERE clause is to filter out cleared but not deleted rows in the input file.

I suspect there is something in the formatting or data of the input Excel file that is causing this. I have had some input files that have not thrown an exception but most do. What is causing this error and how can it be fixed? Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do? Can I perhaps have the user upload a different file format?

**Edit**
Found that checking for null rather than an empty string in the SQL statement works without an exception being thrown.

string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [req_tf_order_no] IS NOT NULL";

Comment: It would probably be better if you posted the Edit as an answer and mark it cause currently it hard to spot plus you should get some points as it's completely legal to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Found that checking for null rather than an empty string in the SQL statement works without an exception being thrown.

string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [req_tf_order_no] IS NOT NULL";